# What is the hotkey for switching workspaces in Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Since I upgraded to Raring my workflow is hindered by abandoning the hotkeys for switching between workspaces. I used `ctrl-alt-left/right/up/down` a lot to switch between workspaces, and `ctrl+alt+shift+left/right/up/down` in order to move windows around.

Currently the only way I see is to launch the workspace switcher with `Super+S`, but I'd like to get the old keys back. How can I do that? Or is there another default combination now?